# Refresh form (Ctrl+F5) doesn't fire Retrieve Plugin in CRM 2011

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

I need to update `entity1` based on creation of `entity2` (math calculation)
while the form of `entity1` is open.

When I refresh the `entity1` form, the field has the old value until I close and open the `entity1` form (the caching issue).

I found out that it doesn't fire the Retrieve Plugin. Is there a way to overcome this issue just by refreshing the form?

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost: latest CRM has `Xrm.Page.data.refresh()` to update form data "automagically" (not to mention the fact that fields self-refresh when changed via plugins).

If upgrading is not an option, I'd setup a "watcher" function like this:

```
// attach to Form Load event
function keepYourFieldInSync() {    
    setInterval(function(){
        var current = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("yourField");

        // Not shown here, basically get the updated value from server
        var fetched = fetch_yourField_value_from_OData_or_SOAP();        

        if(fetched != current){
            Xrm.Page.getAttribute("yourField").setValue(fetched);

            // if users aren't allowed to set the field by hand, I'd also include this
            // and customize the field to be readonly
            Xrm.Page.getAttribute("yourField").setSubmitMode("never");
        }
    }, 1000); // keep it above 500 to avoid killing the browser
}
```

I use a "trick" like this to recognize status changes in Quotes (another user would activate it while this user was working on the draft) and it works quite well.